# How to create a control akin to HTML5 input type: range with support for FF and IE8+?

Tags: html, input, combobox

I was hoping to use HTML5's input control (with range type) to allow our users to click up/down and increment/decrement a value represented inside of the control.

After taking a look at supported browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp, I found that this control was not supported in all the browsers I need it to be supported in.

I did a bit of Googling, but am not sure what keywords I should be using to dig up a more friendly version of this control. It seems all references to the words 'input' and 'range' immediately point me to the HTML5 version.

Does anyone know how I could emulate this functionality while still supporting IE8 and all modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 Input range polyfill could be used.

Details are in this URL : 
http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2010/11/18/unobtrusive-slider-control-html5-input-range-polyfill/

Also, www.HTML5Please.com is an excellent site when stuck with fall back or polyfill doubts.